# How to set pixel's intensity in area of image in python

Tags: python, image, background, pixel, tiff

I have a TIFF image from my experiment as follows:

[image]

However, the background intensity is relatively high, thus I expect to set an area of the image to zero intensity. Do you have any idea to solve this problem in python code?

Would you please help? Thank you so much for consideration.

How to set the intensity of pixels in a range of area in python

Comment: What have you tried to do?

Comment: what did you try? Python has module `pillow` to work with images. But it doesn't have fast function to change every pixel. You may convert `pillow.Image` to `numpy.array` to use faster methods.

Comment: I just use "for" with i and j in condition of pixel size, but seem it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to set the intensities within a shape to zero is draw that shape filled with black:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

# Open image and create drawing context
im = Image.open('z.jpg')
d  = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

# Draw two black triangles
d.polygon((0,0, 780,0, 0,250), 'black')
d.polygon((972,390, 190,390, 972,140), 'black')

# Save result
im.save('result.jpg')
```

[image]

---

Note that I had to crop the image you supplied:

[image]